# How to write nodejs module and pass arguments to it?

Tags: node.js

I am making my nodejs code modular and I am bit confused. I have a working example just wanted to know if it is efficient to do it this way. what i need to do is pass paramater to the module when loading it so that those modules can use some other modules. I have use module.exports to provide a function which returns object. Is this correct way to write modules?

```
var params = {//obj with other modules return};
var api_helper = require('./library/api_helper')(params);
```

my api_helper module

```
module.exports = function (params){
 var app = params.app
 , express = params.express
 , dbConnection = params.dbConnection
 , crypto = params.crypto
 , return_obj = {};
  //validate request
  return_obj.validate_request = function(req, res, next){
    //req validation here
  };
  //check req
  return_obj.checkReq = function (req, res, next){
   //req check here
  }
  return return_obj;
}
```

Comment: V8 and Node handle that for you automatically. You should only care about what your module does and not it's dependencies.

Comment: SO this code is all right?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't require the dependencies directly in api_helper, since it seems it expects some certain modules anyway?

Comment: I think we can directly require it in api_helper. it was just i was passing same params to other modules aswell.

Comment: Here in this link http://book.mixu.net/ch6.html they explain it is bad practice. Should i avoid it?